# How to specify dependencies for a pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift2

I am creating my own pods for sharing common code across several projects. I used 'pod lib create' to create a structure. Where do I specify the dependencies for my own pod? Do I do 'pod init' to create a new Podfile in the root directory of my pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies are supposed to go in your Pod's podspec file, the simplest example can [be](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency) :
`spec.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.0'
spec.dependency 'RestKit/CoreData', '~> 0.20.0'`

Note there are also `spec.libraries` and `spec.frameworks`, and [subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) if that's what you're aiming for - it's unclear from your question.

Comment: Hi I was trying to create my first pod. If my pod classes depends on Alamofire networking library, how do I include it so that my classes can compile?

Comment: If you specify it as a dependency, your includes should work.  you can quickly try it with [cocoapods try](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-try) -- also see [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) for how it actually works.

Comment: I think I got what you meant. Thanks a lot!